# current question: How can I decompile an arm firmware file, to get the device tree file?

Tags: bootable, homebrew, device-tree, openelec, multiboot

I am trying to flash libreelec on an android TV box without having an image I could throw in the libreelec toaster. On the RPi it was quite simple, here I guess I have to compile stuff, I don't really have the answer for.
There is an Image for the previous Box based on S802 (only found a lakka Version(?)), but even though there is libreelec for S812, I don't know who to "compile" it from zip/tar whatever to an actual image for the usb-sd-creator.
Maybe it is easier than it seems, please give me a hint!

Starting question: Does anybody know how to flash/compile Libreelec on a S812 based board?

current question: How can I decompile an arm firmware file , to get the device tree file, which is apperently needed for installing a different operating system on my board?

See:

Toaster: https://libreelec.tv/2016/08/usb-sd-creator/

lakka/libreelec build (.img) for previous box: http://le.builds.lakka.tv/S802.M8.arm/

libreelec build from amlinux.ru e.g. for S812 based box: 
https://mega.nz/#F!W0Qk2JIQ!P1iyw7dFFHvubkIUZ-i1lA!3ohmxIaJ

---

#### 1. How can I create the imagefile for the Toaster from the libreelec build for S812 based board?

Possible solution:

The following page contains a lot of Linux builds for Amlogic boards (S805 S905 S905X S912 (SD and USB):

see: http://freaktab.com/forum/tv-player-support/amlogic-based-tv-players/606133-linux-images-for-s805-s905-s905x-s912-sd-and-usb

---

#### 2. So how can I write a bootable sd-card, which suits the needs for the amlogic board (I guess I can't use the imagetoaster)?

Possible solution:

This page helped a bit, apparently I only need to copy the extracted image (.xz -> .img) via dd on the sd-card, since newer builds contain allready the neccessary files for enabling multiboot for a parallel use of android and linux (which I am explaining later).

> I'm posting both because I know many people are not familiar with the great xz compression format. Download the image that suits your needs and, from a Unix-like system, and running as root, dump it to the MicroSD card you will use to boot your CuBox-i. Say, if your MicroSD card appears as /dev/sdd:

`# dd if=cubox-i.img of=/dev/sdd`

see: https://people.debian.org/~gwolf/

---

#### 3. I finally went with the following instructions to flash linux on the tv box:

> 1.) With the TV box running Android, insert the prepared card in to the box's SD slot or use a USB card reader.
>   Note: I like to use a card reader with activity LED, so I can see something is happening. The first boot can take a few minutes and the flashing LED is reassuring.
>
> 2.) At Android/Settings/About Device/System/updates. Note: You may have the Update and Backup app in the App Drawer.
>   -From the Update and Backup App, under the UpdateLocale section, click Select, select aml_autoscript.zip, click update.
>   Note: Leave "Wipe Data" and "Wipe Media" unchecked/unticked. To be clear, do not use those options
>
> 3.) The TV box will reboot, it will do so a couple of times.
>   Eventually you will see the initial login prompt.
>   Initial login credentials, See here for login info on the different images.
>
> You will be asked to select a new password, do so. You will be asked to create a new User and P/W, do so.
>
> The box will reboot, this boot will be a bit slow, but ultimately should bring you to the desktop.
>   If the card's available space does not get expanded, use gparted(may need to install) to expand the Ext partition to fill the card.
>
> The steps sound far more complicated than they are. Do it once, and you probably won't need this guide the second time.

see: http://freaktab.com/forum/tv-player-support/amlogic-based-tv-players/s905/tronsmart-ac/firmware-roms-tools-at/565449-running-linux-from-sd-card-or-usb-flash-drive-using-balbes150-method-and-files

Results:

Regarding Point 3.3.); Till now the only result after the initialized "update" seems to be, that after each reboot I encounter loss of the HDMI-Signal, so I go and reconnect the HDMI-Cable...
Now I got the nicest bluescreen I have ever seen (I guess it is the bluescreen of the android era...).

---

#### 4. Looks like I have to extract a socalled .dtb file from the actual firmware of my device to apply it to the sd-card ...

If somebody knows an overview site for .dtb files , please post.

see: http://www.cnx-software.com/2014/05/12/how-to-extract-a-device-tree-file-from-android-firmware-files/

Results:

Perfect linux error

> FATAL ERROR: Blob has incorrect magic number

```
    user@user-x:~/Downloads$ unrar x -r ./M8N-M8S_Amlogic_11152015.rar

unrar 0.0.1  Copyright (C) 2004  Ben Asselstine, Jeroen Dekkers


Extracting from /home/user/Downloads/M8N-M8S_Amlogic_11152015.rar

Extracting  n200C-ota-20151103.zip                                    OK        
Extracting  recovery.img                                              OK        
Extracting  u-boot.bin                                                OK        
Extracting  aml_autoscript                                            OK        
Extracting  factory_update_param.aml                                  OK        
Extracting  readme.txt                                                OK        
All OK
user@user-x:~/Downloads$ split_bootimg.pl recovery.img
Page size: 2048 (0x00000800)
Kernel size: 6065155 (0x005c8c03)
Ramdisk size: 2057152 (0x001f63c0)
Second size: 180224 (0x0002c000)
Board name: 
Command line: 
Writing recovery.img-kernel ... complete.
Writing recovery.img-ramdisk.gz ... complete.
Writing recovery.img-second.gz ... complete.
user@user-x:~/Downloads$ dtc -I dtb recovery.img-second.gz -O dts -o meson8_tm8.dtd
FATAL ERROR: Blob has incorrect magic number
user@user-x:~/Downloads$ dtc -I dtb recovery.img-second.gz -O dts -o bla.dtd
FATAL ERROR: Blob has incorrect magic number
user@user-x:~/Downloads$
```

Answer (score 1):

First get the stock recovery partition.

On a PC, download and unzip stock image.
Then unpack firmware.img file with [amlogic unpacker](https://forum.xda-developers.com/android-stick--console-computers/amlogic/tool-amlogic-unpacker-windows-tool-to-t3947923) and find the file `recovery.PARTITION`

or

On the android device terminal, twrp or adb etc, type

`dd if=/dev/block/recovery of=recovery.PARTITION`

Now transfer the **recovery.PARTITION** file to termux home folder or linux home folder.
The DTB file is embedded in this file so now just extract it. Assuming you have already already installed **git, python, perl and wget etc** to termux.

```
#Install binwalk
git clone https://github.com/ReFirmLabs/binwalk.git
cd binwalk
python setup.py install
cd ..; rm -Rf binwalk

#Get split_bootimg.pl script
wget https://gist.githubusercontent.com/jberkel/1087743/raw/45046f87176dfacdc22af4290f89a0d2e0df1dbb/split_bootimg.pl
chmod +x split_bootimg.pl

#Split recovery.PARTITION
./split_bootimg.pl recovery.PARTITION

#Unpack recovery.PARTITION-second.gz
gunzip recovery.PARTITION-second.gz

#Get offset of embedded DTB in recovery.PARTITION-second by searching for bytes D00DFEED
DTBOFFSET=$(binwalk -R "\xD0\x0D\xFE\xED" recovery.PARTITION-second | awk 'NR > 3 { print $1}' | head -n 1)
#Get length of DTB in recovery.PARTITION-second this is next 4 bytes after D00DFEED
DTBLEN=$((16#$(dd if=recovery.PARTITION-second bs=1 skip=$(($DTBOFFSET + 4)) count=4 status=none | od -tx1 | head -n 1 | cut -d ' ' -f 2- | sed 's/ //g' )))
#Now extract and create dtb file
dd if=recovery.PARTITION-second of=mybox.dtb bs=1 skip=$DTBOFFSET count=$DTBLEN
```

Comment: FYI.
An android firmware/recovery or boot partition can contain multiple dtb files.
Also, an android dtb is not compatable with linux.
Already been down that rabbit hole!